# Get the number of pages in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am making lots of changes to a Word document using automation, and then running a VBA macro which - among other things - checks that the document is no more than a certain number of pages.

I'm using `ActiveDocument.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)` to get the number of pages, but this method is returning an incorrect result.  I think this is because Word has not yet updated the pagination of the document to reflect the changes that I've made.

`ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)` also suffers from the same issue.

I've tried sticking in a call to `ActiveDocument.Repaginate`, but that makes no difference.

I did have some luck with adding a paragraph to the end of the document and then deleting it again - but that hack seems to no longer work (I've recently moved from Word 2003 to Word 2010).

Is there any way I can force Word to *actually* repaginate, and/or wait until the repagination is complete?

Comment: both methods you use are correct. maybe you should give it time to recalculate/repaginate before testing number of pages? what kind of changes you do which result with that problem?

Comment: I had similar problem (I don't remember what kind, not num pages, but something similar) and I solved it by showing Word application window (it was hidden).

Comment: @KazJaw: How much time, though :-)  The changes I'm making are mainly adding/removing text, and deleting table rows. The document does have a complex layout, however.

Comment: @Voitcus: unfortunately(?) the application is already visible.

Comment: What about to referencing not to `ActiveDocument` but explicitly to a document object? (you store it in a variable perhaps)

Comment: @Voitcus: actually, I just used `ActiveDocument` in the question to avoid having to "declare" a variable for my example. I do use a variable normally.

Comment: I'm just thinking that there might be a possibility that the document you alter is not the `ActiveDocument`.

Comment: Another couple of possibilities: the page count depends on what is displayed, so e.g. if you have field codes displayed, the page count is "as displayed," which can be longer. Also, ensure ScreenUpdating isn't disabled before you check the count.

Comment: @bibadiak: thanks, I'll check that.

Comment: there is 3rd way to check number of pages, please try this, too: `ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count`

Comment: @bibadiak: no luck :-(

Comment: @KazJaw: same result :-(

Comment: Along the lines of adding a paragraph at the end of the document, if you `Select` the end of the document (ie using `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select`) you can then call `.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)`.  It works fine for me on a really complex 1,177 page document but takes *ages*.

Comment: @CuberChase: I was excited to try it, but... it still made no difference. :-(

Comment: Hmmm. This intrigues me.  Can you provide a bit more information, ie how far out is the page count, is it correct if you just run two lines to select the end of the doc and check the page count.  What view type are you in?

Comment: How about using [`DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)?

Comment: @ashleedawg: As I recall (this question is older than the hills), that made no discernible difference. (It was one of the first things I tried).

Answer (score 11):

I just spent a good 2 hours trying to solve this, and I have yet to see this answer on any forum so I thought I would share it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/pages-object-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

That gave me my solution combined with combing through the articles to find that most of the solutions people reference are not supported in the newest versions of Word. I don't know what version it changed in, but my assumption is that 2013 and newer can use this code to count pages:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count.
```

I believe the way this works is ActiveDocument selects the file, ActiveWindow confirms that the file to be used is in the current window (in case the file is open in multiple windows from the view tab), Panes determines that if there is multiple windows/split panes/any other nonsense you want the "first" one to be evaluated, pages.count designates the pages object to be evaluated by counting the number of items in the collection.

Anyone more knowledgeable feel free to correct me, but this is the first method that gave me the correct page count on any document I tried!

Also I apologize but I cant figure out how to format that line into a code block. If the mods want to edit my comment to do that be my guest.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm not in a position to stress-test it in the way that I have with the other solutions (the other solutions work 90% of the time), but after a quick test it does look promising. The fact that the `Pages` collection can only be accessed when in Print Layout view suggests that it really does take account of page layout. (I do also wonder whether it works when `ScreenUpdating` is off and/or the document is not visible - both things that would reduce its usefulness in automation scenarios).

Answer (score 7):

Try (maybe after `ActiveDocument.Repaginate`)

```
ActiveDocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
```

It is causing my Word 2010 to spend half-second with "Counting words" status in status bar, while `ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)` returns the result immediately.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/185509

Comment: Good shout - can't try it now (this issue was 2 jobs ago), but that sounds worth trying.

Comment: @GaryMcGill Thanks, hope someone else will :)

Comment: @alexkovelsky Works great! Thanks

Comment: My execution-time tests suggest that calling Repaginate prior to ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) is redundant.  The ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) property appears to force a repagination when necessary.

Comment: Also, my testing was done with the application window visible.  So my consistent results may be a function of that state. Gary McGill doesn't say whether that was a factor for him but any functionality that depends on the rendered state of the document image will be unreliable if the application window isn’t visible.  That can apply to the Information property as well as the ComputeStatistics and BuiltinDocumentProperties properties, depending on which operation is requested.

Answer (score 2):

After you've made all your changes, you can use `OnTime` to force a slight delay before reading the page statistics.

```
Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), _
        Name:="UpdateStats"
```

I would also update all the fields before this `OnTime` statement:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Fields.Update
```

Comment: One thing I don't like about delays in cases such as this is ... how long is long enough? On some slow computers, more might be required. It can be difficult to debug :-/

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible workaround below, if not a real answer to the topic question.
Yesterday, the first `ComputeStatistics` line below was returning the correct total of 31 pages, but today it returns only 1.

The solution is to get rid of the `Content` object and the correct number of pages is returned.

```
Dim docMultiple As Document
Set docMultiple = ActiveDocument 
lPageCount = docMultiple.Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)  ' Returns 1
lPageCount = docMultiple.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)  ' Returns correct count, 31
```

Comment: I think what you're seeing is just luck - or rather, a timing issue. ComputeStatistics will return the right result *eventually*, so calling it in a loop, or after a delay - or even calling it twice in some cases - will produce the correct result. The trouble is, it's not predictable enough to make that useful. If you read the question again, you'll see that I was already using ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics, which did not work reliably for me.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)`

This works every time for me. It returns total physical pages in the word.

Comment: That's what I said I was already doing in the question. `ActiveDocument.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)` is the same as `ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)` because `Range` is the default property of `Document`. It works most of the time, but not reliably during automation involving many complex documents.

Answer (score 0):

I used this from within Excel
it worked reliably on about 20 documents
none were longer than 20 pages but some were quite complex
with images and page breaks etc.

```
Sub GetlastPageFromInsideExcel()
Set wD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set myDoc = wD.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\mydocument.docx")
myDoc.Characters.Last.Select        ' move to end of document
wD.Selection.Collapse               ' collapse selection at end
lastPage = wD.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
mydoc.close
wd.quit
Set wD = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I had in getting "ComputeStatistics" to return a correct page count was that I often work in "Web Layout" view in Word. Whenever you start Word it reverts to the last view mode used. If Word was left in "Web Layout" mode "ComputeStatistics" returned a page count of "1" page for all files processed by the script. Once I specifically set "Print Layout" view I got the correct page counts.

For example:

```
$MSWord.activewindow.view.type = 3    # 3 is 'wdPrintView', 6 is 'wdWebView'
$Pages = $mydoc.ComputeStatistics(2)  # 2 is 'wdStatisticPages'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pages-Object and its properties such as Count. It works perfect;)

Dim objPages As Pages
Set objPage = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages

QuantityOfPages = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count

Comment: Thanks. That was already suggested in the highest-voted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531460/98422
I'm no longer in a position to try it, unfortunately. Or rather, fortunately :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim wordapp As Object
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)

Dim pagesCount As Integer
pagesCount = doc.Content.Information(4) 'wdNumberOfPagesInDocument
doc.Close False
Set doc = Nothing
```

Comment: This solution was already discussed - and discounted - in the question. It works fine 90% of the time, but if you're manipulating the document through VBA it fails to give you an up-to-date result that reflects the changes you've made.